# width: calc() not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, width, calc

I have the following CSS properties on an item:

```
width: calc(100%- 40px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
```

but Firefox is saying that they are both invalid property values. Is this a bug with Firefox, or is there a new way to do width: calc in Firefox?

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc 
"Note: The + and - operators must be surrounded by whitespace. For instance, calc(50% -8px) will be parsed as a percentage followed by a negative length—an invalid expression—while calc(50% - 8px) is a percentage followed by a subtraction operator and a length. Likewise, calc(8px + -50%) is treated as a length followed by an addition operator and a negative percentage."

Comment: You need a space in `calc(100%- 40px);`. Ex: `calc(100% - 40px);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-moz-calc` CSS function [has been removed](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/moz-calc-has-been-removed/) with Firefox 53. Just use `calc` and make sure you have white space between parameters:

correct:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

incorrect:

```
width: calc(100%- 40px);
```

Comment: What about this   width: calc( 100% / 5 );? Is it correct?

Comment: Division operator works in calc function when right hand is a number. For more accuracy remove the space before and after parentheses @NarenVerma

Answer (score 2):

Firefox browsers support the `calc` function as shown in the browser compatibility at the bottom of this [mozilla web developer reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), only there is a specific note about the whitespace as noted on that page and the [official W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#typedef-calc-sum):

> In addition, white space is required on both sides of the + and - operators. (The * and / operaters can be used without white space around them.)

Your example would work by adding an additional whitespace in front of the `-` symbol like so:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

As for the `-moz-calc()` function, according to the official Firefox development channels they [removed](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/moz-calc-has-been-removed/) the support of this function since January 2017 and recommend use of the standard `calc()` function.

Comment: Great question! My answer contains a link to the browser compatibility chart, and an excerpt from the official W3 documentation. I didn't refresh my browser right before submitting so didn't know that you commented and that someone provided an answer while I was typing up my answer so thus my answer while slower with more links seems redundant to you ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Thank you @j08691 for pointing that out!